# MVC with vue (data from database)

Tags: vue.js, model-view-controller

I have a mvc project and on the front-end side I need to use vue. How do I bind my vue script with current model, so I can get data from database? (I'm just starting to use vue)
(I found out that I probably need to use axios, but have no idea how.)

Comment: it isnt that hard. here read about it: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is good article for Build a Simple CRUD App with ASP.NET Framework 4.x Web API and Vue

[Build a Simple CRUD App with ASP.NET](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/07/build-simple-crud-with-aspnet-webapi-vue)

Answer (score 0):

You don't NEED axios, you can also just use the vanilla JS fetch() method, then you don't need to import axios.

You need to have a backend system which responsibility is to deal with the database and to provide the endpoints for axios (or fetch()) to fetch/post data from/to. Here you have plenty of options.

- If you already know javascript probably you can set up a node.js server to do this for you.
- If you know python then FLASK is the easiest and fastest way to set up a CRUD* server (if security is not highest priority).
- Else there are a lot of possibilities here, it just depends on what programming language you want to use.

*CRUD = Create - Read - Update - Delete